# In The Walking Dead, what did Dr. Jenner tell Rick?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In the episode "TS-19", Dr. Jenner whispers something into Rick's ear before they leave the CDC which leaves Rick visibly shaken.

What exactly does he tell him?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is revealed in Season 2, Episode #13 "[Beside the Dying Fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beside_the_Dying_Fire)". Jenner tells Rick that

> No matter how you die, you always come back as a walker - in other words, everyone is already infected. This comes after other survivors ask how Randall turned without being bitten and after we see Shane come back without being bitten. However he did have a scratch on his stomach.

Comment: That's not true otherwise Rick would have mentioned that to Shane in the episode where they found the two guards with no bite marks on them. Its not explained that you turn even if not bitten until season three.

Comment: Its revealed at minute 32 of S02E13: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=221utkUgeJc

Answer (score 2):

He basically tells Rick that the infection is air born therefore everyone is infected. Which enhances the meaning of the shows title, since they're all infected that means when they die they'll turn, which also means they are technically the walking dead.

Comment: What are you basing this on? The original scene has Jenner whispering inaudibly (to the viewer). Rick only says that Jenner told him that they were all already infected - never saying *anything* about how the infection was spread.

Answer (score -5):

I think he told him that its a virus that's in the air and everyone is infected and one of the members of his group has a rare blood type that could be used as a cure.

Comment: Could you site a reference to this?

Comment: This directly contradicts what Rick says to the group in Season 2, and Jenner does not exist in the comics (yet).This supposed rare blood type would have prevented Shane changing into a walker without being bit.  So, what are you basing this on?